# Разумно ли поднимать несколько Gunicorn/Celery воркеров внутри одного контейнера?

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn, devops

Недавно при попытке развернуть NodeJS кластер внутри docker на машине с 4-я ядрами обратил внимание на то, что докер "видит" только одно ядро, и как мне на текущий момент известно, это архитектурный нюанс докера.

Потом нагуглил много информации в духе "один процесс один контейнер" и т.п.

Появился вопрос, насколько это всё правда и как с этим жить и работать?

Разумно ли внутри контейнера поднимать несколько воркеров celery или gunicorn, если ядро доступно только одно?

Или лучше поднимать один процесс celery/gunicorn и скейлить это дело количеством контейнеров?

Comment: разумно использовать инструмент именно для того, для чего он создавался (и развивается дальше): для запуска процесса (одного) в изолированном окружении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js под капотом и так воркеров имеет в ивентлупе. Так что, у вас они и так уже используются по дефолту, если вы ноду используете.

> Появился вопрос, насколько это все правда и как с этим жить и
>   работать? Разумно ли внутри контейнера поднимать несколько воркеров
>   celery или gunicorn, если ядро доступно только одно?

Тут всё зависит от того, что вы подразумеваете под воркерами. К примеру, если работать без докера, люди часто используют штук типо supervisord'а для запуска несколько процессов ноды. Вот так делать не рекомендуется. Лучше запустить несколько докер контейнеров с одним процессом сервиса внутри, а скейлить на уровне штуки, которая рулит докер контейнерами (k8s?).